# Does the ordering of a Schauder basis matter in Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, conditional-convergence, schauder-basis

**If $S=\{v_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is a (not necessarily orthogonal) Schauder basis for a Hilbert space $H$, must $S$ be an *unconditional* Schauder basis?** I define these terms below because not every source I have found agrees perfectly on the definitions.

On general Banach spaces (where orthogonality is undefined), there exist conditional Schauder bases. But if the Schauder basis is on a Hilbert space and is orthogonal, then it is indeed unconditional. So my question is therefore whether this unconditional property remains if we stay in Hilbert space but orthogonality is removed.

---

**Definitions:**

An ordered countable subset $\{v_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ of a Banach space $V$ is a **Schauder basis** if every $v\in V$ can be written uniquely as a series $v=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i v_i$, where convergence is with respect to the norm-induced topology.

A Schauder basis is **unconditional** if the terms of any convergent series can be rearranged without affecting the sum.

A **Hilbert basis** is a maximal orthonormal subset of a Hilbert space $H$, possibly uncountable. It is known that even for non-separable Hilbert spaces, there exists a Hilbert basis $B$, and that every $v\in H$ can be expressed uniquely as a sum of a countable subset of $B$, which is always independent of summation order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a "cheating" way to get a conditional Schauder basis on a Hilbert space. Take an orthogonal Schauder basis $v_i$ and consider a convergent series $\sum\alpha_iv_i$. Now let $\beta_i$ be some conditionally convergent series in $\mathbb R$ and consider the new Schauder basis $w_i =  v_i + \frac{\beta_i}{\alpha_i}v_1$. $\sum\alpha_iw_i$ must converge conditionally.

Comment: Very nice and simple. So the unconditionality of Hilbert bases really relies on their orthogonality.